# How to give validation to crud operations using java sprint boot. Which return true or false in response body

Tags: spring-boot, postman

[In image in marked area(green box) should return true in response instead of employeeid,name etc ps: this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz2V3.jpg)My question is what will be the code for java spring boot (in service class)which return true or false in response body after performing crud operations ( create(Post), Update( Put), Get)
For example in postman if we send request in json format using Post it should return true if new entry is created...(not shown json format in response body)
If we try to enter duplicate entry then it should return/show false)in response body.
If we delete entry by id then it should return true and if id not present then should return false.
What should add in below code to get response true in response

```
private static HashMap<Integer, Book> bookMap = new HashMap<Integer, Books();

public Book createBook(Book bookToBeCreated) {
    bookMap.put(bookToBeCreated.getId(), bookToBeCreated); 
    return bookToBeCreated;
}

public Book getBook(Integer bookId) {
  return bookMap.get(bookId);
}

public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
   List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>(bookMap.values());
   return bookList;
}

public Book updateBook(Book bookToBeUpdated) {
   bookMap.put(bookToBeUpdated.getId(), bookToBeUpdated);
   return bookToBeUpdated;
}
```

Comment: What you are describing is better accomplished with response headers. Example would be a 201 for created, or 400 -bad request for a duplicate. You'd need to provide what your current resource class looks like to get a better answer on implementation.  
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers

Comment: I should have been more clear. Could you edit the question to include the code (not a screenshot). It makes it much easier to answer questions this way.

Comment: You'd just have the functions return a Boolean (object not primitive).  However this would require you to write logic to handle it and you may need to change the response media type. The typical way to handle it is through http response headers though like I said.

Comment: The image showing that when i do POST in postman it returns the "id" = 1, "name"= "Abc" like this in response body  but i wanted to show true in response body instead of "id" = 1, "name"= "Abc" how to do that what code should i do to return true in response instead of  that

Comment: public Book createBook would become public Boolean createBook and the method would have to return a boolean instead of the newly created object.

Comment: Great! Posted it as an answer. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

public Book createBook would become public Boolean createBook and the method would have to return a boolean instead of the newly created object.